# COUNT(totals.visits) - is it an accurate measure of sessions?

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

I am trying to write a query in Google BQ where our GA data is exported. The query is below

```
SELECT visitStartTime,date,,hits.eCommerceAction.*,count(totals.visits) 
FROM flatten([bigquery-xxxxxx:xxxxxxxx.ga_sessions_20180925],hits.eCommerceAction)
WHERE hits.eCommerceAction.action_type <> '0'
GROUP BY date,visitStartTime,hits.eCommerceAction.action_type,hits.eCommerceAction.option,hits.eCommerceAction.step
LIMIT 1000
```

The output from this looks something like this

```
date      hits_type  hits_step  hits_option f0_
20180925  5          1          1           0
20180925  2          1          0           1
```

My question is that when there is an ecommerce hit being sent, how can the session count be 0? (`f0` column). Since `totals.visits` can return 1 or NULL and since count only counts non NULL values, should I be counting any other field like `visitID` to avoid NULLs? All tutorials online are shown as using `totals.visits` so I am confused whether I am missing something here.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If there is only non interaction hits in the session, totals.visits will be null. If you want to include both interaction and non interaction hits then it's correct to count unique visitId+fullVisitorId combinations.